# How do I specify my custom agent in the build pipeline?

Tags: vb6, azure-devops

I am following [Donovan Brown's blog post](http://donovanbrown.com/post/Build-Visual-Basic-60-applications-with-Visual-Studio-Team-Services) to try and setup a build agent for VB6

I can see my agent in the agent pools
[image: Agent Pools]

but don't know what to put as the image.
[image: build pipeline]

I tried Default and I tried vb6vm3 but was unable to save the pipeline with these values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Target the desired Queue, not the Pool.  Try replacing the pool code with the code below.

```
  queue:
    name: Default
```

I also find it easier to use the graphical user interface to create my build and use the Show YAML button to get the yaml written for me.

Comment: Next question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54798209/how-do-i-set-up-the-copy-files-task-in-azure-devops-after-a-vb6-build

Comment: queue and pool both work. However intellisense does not like queue

Answer (score 3):

> How do I specify my custom agent in the build pipeline?

I have encountered the same issue as you. To resolve this issue, I try to create a new build pipeline by using the visual designer, select my custom private agent, then select the options View YAML:

[image]

I got following code:

```
pool:
  name: VS2017PrivateAgent
```

And it works fine.

**But** I am still curious why I can not use `pool:vmImage` and how add my private agent option to the drop-down menu.

After search much info, I found the reason in an inconspicuous place [Pool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema#pool):

```
pool:
  name: string  # name of the pool to run this job in
  demands: string | [ string ]  ## see below
  vmImage: string # name of the vm image you want to use, only valid in the Microsoft-hosted pool
```

The comment **name of the vm image you want to use, only valid in the Microsoft-hosted pool** is the real reason I could not use `pool:vmImage`.

And

> If you're using a private pool and don't need to specify demands, this
>   can be shortened to:
>
> `pool: string # name of the private pool to run this job in`

Hope this can give more info about this issue.

Comment: Really if the pick list is only a subset of what is possible it would be better if it was not available.