# How do I set up the Copy Files Task in Azure Devops after a VB6 build?

Tags: vb6, azure-pipelines

In response to [this question about making an Azure build pipeline for a VB6 project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54796027/how-do-i-specify-my-custom-agent-in-the-build-pipeline)

I have managed to create the following Build Pipeline so far

```
pool:
  name: Default
steps:
- script: |
   echo Write your commands here

   echo Use the environment variables input below to pass secret variables to this script
  vb6.exe /m /out errors.txt Project1.vbp
  workingDirectory: 'C:\dev\hello'
  failOnStderr: true
  displayName: vb6

- powershell: |
   # Write your powershell commands here.

   Write-Host "Hello World"

   # Use the environment variables input below to pass secret variables to this script.


   if(Test-Path .\errors.txt)
   {
      $file = Get-Content .\errors.txt 
      Remove-Item .\errors.txt

      if($file | Select-String "succeeded." -quiet) { exit 0 }

      $file | Where-Object {Write-Host "##vso[task.logissue type=error]$_"}
   }
  displayName: 'PowerShell Script'
```

When I run it, the .EXE does get created on the Agent.

Next I want to copy the .EXE and .DLLs to an Azure Storage location.

I understand I need to use the Copy Files Task and then a Publish Task.

I am trying to use the designer to figure out the YAML for the Copy Files Task

[image: Copy Files task]  but I don't know what to put. The target text box is not allowing input.

[Update]

I have been able to add the following task after studying [the help](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/copy-files?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)
However no files get copied.

```
  - task: CopyFiles@2
  inputs:
    contents: '*c:\dev\hello\*.exe*' 
    targetFolder: c:\dev\out2
```

Comment: Strange. Have you set anything, just a new pipeline with new copy task? How about create a new one? For the Copy Files task, you can check the details from: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/copy-files?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

Comment: Thanks @LeoLiu-MSFT I updated the question

Answer (score 3):

```
  - task: CopyFiles@2
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: c:\dev\hello
    contents: '**.exe*'
    targetFolder: c:\dev\out2
```

where c:\dev\hello is the location of the project on the build agent

[Update]

And a nicer notation that allows for multiple file types is

```
- task: CopyFiles@2
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: c:\dev\hello
    contents:  |
              *.exe
              *.dll
    targetFolder: c:\dev\out2
```

Comment: next problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54800409/unexpected-property-pathtopublish

Comment: used the same way but not working.