# Unexpected property pathtoPublish

Tags: azure-devops

After [copying files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54798209/how-do-i-set-up-the-copy-files-task-in-azure-devops-after-a-vb6-build)

I am trying to implement a task to publish the copied files.

Looking at [the help](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/publish-build-artifacts?view=azure-devops)

I think I should be able to use

```
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
  pathtoPublish: '..\out2'
  displayName: 'Publish Artifact: drop'
```

but intellisense tells me

```
unexpected property pathtoPublish
```

When I try to save anyway I get

```
Could not queue the build because there were validation errors or warnings. /azure-pipelines.yml (Line: 41, Col: 10): Unexpected value '' /azure-pipelines.yml (Line: 42, Col: 3): Unexpected value 'pathtoPublish'
```

Strangely Intellisense also indicates an issue with

```
inputs:
```

The error is

```
Incorrect type. Expected "object"
```

[image: Incorrect type]

[Update]

Indenting 2 spaces as suggested by Yan helps, but raises some new issues

[image: displayName]

[Update]

I changed to

```
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '..\out2'
    ArtifactName: drop'
```

and was able to save the YAML
When it runs it gives the error

```
Publishing build artifacts failed with an error: Not found PathtoPublish: C:\Users\kgreed\Downloads\vsts-agent-win-x64-2.147.1\_work\1\out2
```

Comment: Could the indentation be the reason? what if you indent the `pathtoPublish` two spaces to the right? It will probably tell the engine that `pathtoPublish` is related to `inputs`, not to the `task` itself. If that's the case, then it will most likely resolve the other error too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pathtoPublish should be indented:

```
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    pathtoPublish: '..\out2'
    ArtifactName: drop
```

example\reading: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/publish-build-artifacts?view=azure-devops

Comment: this means the path doesnt exist, I suppose you need to start a new question for that one, as your original error is solved

Comment: Thanks for the tip.

Comment: I put the full path in and then it worked... even though I had come across help that said the relative path was required.

Comment: relative path is better, as full path will only work with this specific agent