# What do the pipeline settings do, since they do not effect the YAML

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

In researching [my question about custom agents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54796027/how-do-i-specify-my-custom-agent-in-the-build-pipeline)
I found that I could choose an agent in the Pipeline settings.

[image: Choose an agent]

This will not effect the choice of agent in the actual YAML for the pipeline.
So what is it fore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are irrelevant for the yaml pipeline if you define the agent, however, you might not define it and they are still the only way to pick agent for non yaml tasks.